# Google drive and similar cloud services

Tags: cloud-hosting, google-drive-api, mobile-application, file-sharing

I have one hypothetic question.
Can I use some cloud drive for storing content and sharing it with many and many users? For instance, I have a single google account that contain a set of files (few gigabytes e.g.) and some appliction (e.g. iOS app) that mounts google drive and access files it contains. I can't find any info either it's restricted or not. Maybe you can recommend some other solution? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create shared folders on Google Drive that can be accessed by any user via opening the URL in their browser.  Details on sharing folders with Google Drive can be found [here](http://support.google.com/drive/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2494822).